# Query data with SalesforceSharp

Tags: rest-api, rest, c#, .net

I can extract data from SalesForce with the following code:

```
namespace SalesForceExtractCsv
{
    public class Account
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
    }

    public class Program
    {
        public static string client_id = "id here";
        public static string client_secret = "secret here";
        public static string un = "username";
        public static string pw = "password";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var client = new SalesforceClient();
            var authFlow = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFlow(client_id, client_secret, un, pw);

            try
            {
                client.Authenticate(authFlow);
            }
            catch (SalesforceException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Authentication failed: {0} : {1}", ex.Error, ex.Message);
            }

            IList<Account> records = client.Query<Account>("SELECT id, name, description, type FROM Account");

            CsvConfiguration config = new CsvConfiguration();
            config.Delimiter = ";";

            using(var sw = new StreamWriter(@"testcsv.csv"))
            {
                var writer = new CsvWriter(sw, config);


                writer.WriteRecords(records);
            }


        }
    }
}
```

I use the SalesForce sharp library to extract the data, but from it's not clear to me how this works exactly. I get it that the API is abstracting a rest interface, but how do I find out which values are valid in the SELECT clause and the FROM clause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume by the SalesForce sharp library you mean the [SalesforceSharp project](https://github.com/giacomelli/SalesforceSharp) on Github?

If so, it appears the only support for Metadata is the [SalesforceClient.ReadMetaData method](https://github.com/giacomelli/SalesforceSharp/blob/master/src/SalesforceSharp/SalesforceClient.cs#L215).

> Obtains a JSON representation of fields an meta data for a given object type

You should be able to parse the available fields for an sObject from there.

---

You will that the [Force.com-Toolkit-for-NET](https://github.com/developerforce/Force.com-Toolkit-for-NET) is more active if you want to work from .NET to the Salesforce REST API.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that if you look at the standard objects list:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_list.htm

You put the standard object name in the FROM clause and the standard object fields in the SELECT clause.